# Access complex data properties using HtmlHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am coding an extension helper similar to `DisplayFor` in MVC but the advantage of mine is that it will retrieve the actual property name from the resources file.

```
public class Gender
    {
       public int Id{get;set;}
       public string Name{get; set;}
       public string ArabicName{get;set;}
    }

public class Employee
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string ArabicName{get;set;}
    public Gender Gender{get;set;}
}

public static MvcHtmlString DisplayResourceFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            var rm = new ResourceManager("Resources.Global",
                System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));                
            var property = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
            string resourceName = string.Empty;
            var split = property.Split('.');
            property = string.Empty;
            // rebuild the expression taking the last name from the resource file
            for (var index = 0; index < split.Length; index++)
            {
                if (index == split.Length - 1) // retrieve the data from rm
                    property += (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(property) ? "" : ".") + rm.GetString(string.Format("{0}Resource", split[index]));
                else
                    property += (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(property) ? "" : ".") + split[index];
            }
            var value = helper.ViewContext.ViewData.GetViewDataInfo(property);

            return value == null ? MvcHtmlString.Empty : MvcHtmlString.Create(value.Value.ToString());

        }
```

the above code will not work with complex data like

```
@Html.DisplayResourceFor(model =>model.Gender.Name)
```

I tried to use `ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(property,helper.ViewData)` but the returned values was empty

what is the missing part in my code?

any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: what are you trying to do? why not use metadata and `Display` attribute? The `Display` attribute supports localization for properties! They accomplish the same work as you and thous prevent you from trying to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @bellash I am trying to localize the data itself also, for example Bellesh in English, بيليش in arabic